# PyTorch having trouble detecting CUDA

Tags: pytorch

I am running CNN on PyTorch. The torch.cuda.is_available() function returned false and no GPU is detected. However, I can run Keras model with GPU. Here is my system information:

- OS: Ubuntu 18.04.3
- Python 3.7.3 (Conda)
- GPU: GTX1080Ti
- Nvidia driver: 430.50

When I check nvidia-smi, the output said that the CUDA version is 10.1. However, the nvcc -V command tells me that it is CUDA 9.1.

I downloaded NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-430.50.run from the official site and install it with command line. I installed CUDA 10.1 using these following command line recommended by the official site:

```
wget http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/10.1/Prod/local_installers/cuda_10.1.243_418.87.00_linux.run
sudo sh cuda_10.1.243_418.87.00_linux.run
```

I installed PyTorch through pip install. What is wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

The default Pytorch 1.2 package depends on CUDA 10.0, but you have CUDA 9.1. The output of `nvidia-smi` just tells you the maximum CUDA version your GPU supports, `nvcc` gives the CUDA installed on your system. It seems that your installation of CUDA 10.1 was unsuccessful.

In addition to CUDA 10.0, Pytorch also supports CUDA 9.2 and I've found that the Pytorch package compiled for CUDA 10.0 also works with CUDA 10.1. So you can either upgrade your CUDA installation to 9.2 and install the Pytorch CUDA 9.2 package with

```
pip3 install torch==1.2.0+cu92 torchvision==0.4.0+cu92 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

Or get a working installation of CUDA 10.1. There are detailed Linux instructions [here.](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html) (Note that you may have to remove previous installations of CUDA before installing a new one.)

Comment: I just installed CUDA 10.0 and the nvcc still told me my version is 9.1. Here is the information when I finished installation. It's the same as the time when I installed CUDA 10.1:
===========
= Summary =
===========

Driver:   Not Selected
Toolkit:  Installed in /usr/local/cuda-10.0
Samples:  Installed in /home/kaiming

Please make sure that
 -   PATH includes /usr/local/cuda-10.0/bin
 -   LD_LIBRARY_PATH includes /usr/local/cuda-10.0/lib64, or, add /usr/local/cuda-10.0/lib64 to /etc/ld.so.conf and run ldconfig as root

Comment: Please ask a new question with problems related to installing CUDA. You may have to remove previous installations

Comment: Turns out I just need to reinstall PyTorch after CUDA is installed. Silly me.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, this answer is a *hack* which could mess up your conda env, but may work more easily than installing a fresh env. A consistency-checking tool would be really helpful because of all the people having exactly this problem. Matching anaconda's CUDA version with the system driver and the actual hardware and the other system environment settings is challenging to say the least and almost an art.

I found that Anaconda improperly guesses the CUDA version to use frequently. So I have found the best way to fix this is to surgically uninstall and reinstall *just* pytorch with pip:

```
pip uninstall torch
pip install torch
```

Note that pip calls pytorch `torch` while conda calls it `pytorch`.

However, I also found that pip sometimes refuses to reinstall torch because it didn't get rid of the anaconda site package files. If that is the case you can very carefully remove them manually as:

```
rm -fr $HOME/miniconda3/envs/<ENV>/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/
rm -fr $HOME/miniconda3/envs/<ENV>/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch-*.dist-info/
```

where  should be replaced with your environment name and `miniconda` might be `anaconda` or something else depending on your installation.

Be *very* careful not to delete anything other than the torch files or you may mess something else up. Then you would be best served by installing yet another fresh environment.

After this `pip install torch` should work and `torch.cuda.is_available()` should return `True`. Unless there is another problem... YMMV.

Note that I recommend using miniconda because the full anaconda comes overloaded with packages and I find it quickly gets clogged and broken.