# Pytorch detection of CUDA

Tags: python, pytorch

Which is the **command** to see the "correct" CUDA Version that `pytorch` in conda env is seeing?  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58005297/pytorch-having-trouble-detecting-cuda), is a similar question, but doesn't get me far.

1. `nvidia-smi` says I have cuda version `10.1`
2. `conda list` tells me cudatoolkit version is `10.2.89`
3. `torch.cuda.is_available()` shows FALSE, so it sees `No CUDA`?
4. `print(torch.cuda.current_device())`, I get `10.0.10` (10010??) (it
   looks like):

   > AssertionError: The NVIDIA driver on your system is too old
   > (found version 10010)
5. `print(torch._C._cuda_getCompiledVersion(), 'cuda compiled version')` tells me my version is `10.0.20` (10020??)?

   > 10020 cuda compiled version

Why are there so many different versions? What am I missing?

P.S
I have Nvidia driver `430` on Ubuntu 16.04 with Geforce 1050. It comes
with `libcuda1-430` when I installed the driver from `additional drivers` tab in ubuntu (`Software and Updates`). I installed `pytorch`
with `conda` which also installed the `cudatoolkit` using `conda install -c fastai -c pytorch -c anaconda fastai`

Comment: Ignore `nvidia-smi`. The easiest way is to reinstall latest nvidia driver and pytorch.

Comment: PyTorch is delivered with its own cuda and cudnn. Therefore, you only need a compatible nvidia driver installed in the host. So, the question is with which cuda was your PyTorch built? Check that using `torch.version.cuda`. So, let's say the output is `10.2`. Then, you [check whether your nvidia driver is compatible or not](https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/cuda-compatibility/index.html#binary-compatibility). BTW, nvidia-smi basically tells that your driver supports up to CUDA 10.1, not that it is actually installed (which is not required for using PyTorch, unless you want to compile something).

Comment: @Berriel thank you very much for the clarification. It says 10.2. am positive that 10.2 doens't work with `430` according to your [link](https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/cuda-compatibility/index.html#binary-compatibility). Unfortunately I can't go higher than `nvidia-430`  as it is not for `ubuntu 16.04`.

Comment: @Berriel, So I tried installing the right `cudatoolkit` (`10.0.130` which is supposed to work with `430`) with `conda install -c pytorch cudatoolkit=10.0.130`. But this led to [this massive error](https://pastebin.com/NG8hRY7N) with conflicts in `Conda`. And I am honestly lost as to where to start with such an error. :( Appreciate any help! thank you once again.

Comment: Not exactly sure about how this should be done with conda, but I would uninstall pytorch torchvision and cudatoolkit and just run the recommended command from pytorch.org: `conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.1 -c pytorch`. I usually go with pip, and for me I would simply go to https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html and find the appropriate version.

Comment: @Berriel  as per your advise I did: `conda remove pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit` and then `conda install pytorch==1.6.0 torchvision==0.7.0 cudatoolkit=10.1.168
-c pytorch`. `torch.version.cuda` = 10.1 :) I had in total of 0 exceptions, 0 errors. Seemed smooth as long as I nodded [Y] to the `## Package Plan##`.

Comment: somehow `fastai` got removed. `conda install -c pytorch -c fastai fast ai` solved it. P.S. @Berriel, Mighty thanks. For the first time in 1 week I see my GPU WORK and crunch numbers super fast. Indebted. I will write a clear answer below based on this learning. thank you so much.

Comment: Great! Have fun :)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

In the conda env (myenv) where pytorch is installed do the following:

```
conda activate myenv

torch.version.cuda
```

`Nvidia-smi` only shows compatible version. Does not seem to talk about the version `pytorch`'s own cuda is built on.

Comment: Usually the CUDA version for pytorch comes with it... Look at `pytorch`'s documentation to be able to select a cuda version that works for you.

Comment: The answer for: "Which is the command to see the "correct" CUDA Version that pytorch in conda env is seeing?" would be: `conda activate my_env` and then `conda list | grep cuda`. This should show you the version of cuda and cudnn used by pytorch.

Comment: I have cuda-10.2 and cuda-11.1 installed in my system. I exported the PATH for cuda-11.1 for my environment. ```which nvcc``` returns ```cuda-11.1``` but ```torch.version.cuda``` shows ```10.2```. What can be done?

Comment: @AjinkyaAmbatwar what do you want to be done? Is your goal to use pytorch and hence cuda in a conda environment?